# Geodesics in general relativity changing from timelike to spacelike?

Tags: general-relativity, causality, geodesics

Is it possible for geodesic in general relativity to be time-like, and at some point cross null-plane and become space-like?

Comment: I've edited the question to provide a more descriptive title. In general, please use titles that are as specific as possible.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible for geodesic in general relativity to be time-like, and at some point cross null-plane and become space-like?

No. One way of defining a geodesic is that it parallel-transports its own tangent vector. Parallel transport preserves the norm, so it can't change a timelike vector to a spacelike one.

Answer (score 1):

> Tomek asked: Is it possible for geodesic in general relativity to be
>   time-like, and at some point cross null-plane and become space-like?

As Ben Crowell already said, that is not possible. After you crossed the horizon of a black hole your velocity relative to the singularity will indeed exceed the speed of light, but you would have to be on a spacelike path in order to keep a constant distance behind the horizon, or on a lightlike path to stay stationary at the horizon, which you can't because as a massive observer you are forever confined to a timelike path. Also you can never overtake a photon, neither outside nor inside of the horizon. Therefore on a Penrose diagram the path of a massive particle must always be inside the light cone and have an angle steeper than 45°, inside and outside the horizon. To cite [MTW, exercise 13.5](http://org.yukterez.net/mtw.13.5,p.321.png):

> MTW wrote: A geodesic which is timelike at one event is everywhere
>   timelike. Similarly, a geodesic initially spacelike is everywhere
>   spacelike, and a geodesic initially lightlike is everywhere lightlike.